# Aligning arrow fo Chemical reaction and much more

Tags: chemfig, chemistry

My chemical reaction latex codes look like this

```
\document[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}

\schemestart
\chemname{\chemfig{R-H}}{Alkane} \arrow(.{5.5}--){->[light,heat or catalyst]}[0,2,] \chemname{\chemfig{R-X}}{Haloalkane} \+ \chemfig{HX}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_4} \+ \chemfig{Cl_2} \arrow(.{5.5}--){->[light]}[0,2,] \chemfig{CH_3Cl} \+ \chemfig{HCl}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3Cl}  \+ \chemfig{Cl_2} \arrow(.{5.5}--){->[light]}[0,2,] \chemfig{CH_2Cl_2} \+ \chemfig{HCl}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_2Cl_2}  \+ \chemfig{Cl_2} \arrow(.{5.5}--){->[light]}[0,2,] \chemfig{CHCl_3} \+ \chemfig{HCl}
\schemestop

\schemestart
\chemfig{CH_3Cl}  \+ \chemfig{Cl_2} \arrow(.{5.5}--){->[light]}[0,2,] \chemfig{CCl_4} \+ \chemfig{HCl}
\schemestop

\end{document}
```

It looks like this on compiling [image]

I thought adding \arrow{0}[,0] will fix it but it didn't actually i don't' know why :( . But i think it works for reaction containing benzene etc :(

- +How to i balance the position of arrow of chemical reaction ?
- How to i give blue color to Cl_2 atoms ? i thought of adding \colors but dont' know how it works :(
- How do i show all arrow of same length ?
- How to i show these reaction with arrow center so it
  looks very nice ?
- How to i reduce the distance between names of compound and their names?

Thank you .

Comment: I'd do those kind of reactions either with  the `chemformula` or the `mhchem` package. Both `\ch` (`chemformula`) and `\ce` (`mhchem`) can be used in `amsmath`'s `align` environment for alignment

Comment: @clemens Thanks clemens . I am learning chemfig as many people recommended. Is it good to learn chemformula or mhchem?

Comment: `chemformula` and `mhchem` are alternatives to each other but both can be used quite well together with `chemfig`

Comment: @clemens thanks can chemformula and mhchem works like chemfig . I mean for example drawing benzene ?

Comment: No but they do other things very well where `chemfig` is not the ideal soultion. Why don't you have a look at them and decide for yourself?

Comment: @clemens ok. but can you answer some of the things like reducing distance between names and structure?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25110/discussion-between-aftershock-and-clemens).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically the answer is: have a look at TikZ anchors and how to use them with `chemfig`'s `\arrow`:

```
\arrow(<node name>.<anchor>--<node name>.<anchor>)
```

All node names and anchors are optional. Those can be used with an invisible downarrow (angle: -90) to achieve alignment, e.g., by aligning the lower right-hand edge of the upper compound (`south west`) with the upper right-hand edge of the lower compound (`north west`):

```
\arrow(@c1.south east--.north east)
```

Here is an example alignment:

```
% \schemedebug{true} % shows (not only) the node names
\schemestart
  % line one
  A + B \arrow C + D
  \arrow(@c1.south east--.north east){0}[-90,.15]
  % line two:
  E + F \arrow G + H
  \arrow(@c3.south east--.north east){0}[-90,.15]
  % line three:
  I + J \arrow K + L
\schemestop
```

[image]

or with `\schemedebug{true}`:

[image]

---

Coloring can be done by placing braces around the atom and adding `\color{blue}`

```
\chemfig{CH_3-{\color{blue}Cl}}
```

---

As for the distance between compounds and names: I supsect you have used `\chemname` not in a group somewhere and have forgotten to reset it. Have a look at [Placement of caption in \chemfig via \chemname command - how to reset spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83236)