# Chemfig too large distance between Compounds and names?

Tags: chemfig

There is large space between the compound name and compound . I used arrow[0]{,0} also and cyclohexane is not aligned properly at center :(

picture explains clearly :(
[image]

How do i remove distance between c1 and benzene as well as c4 and cyclohexane .

How ever the main problem is adding [0.8ex] fixes for some compounds with names like the screenshot below .
[image]

You can see at c1 c2 there is no problem but in second c1 and c4 there is huge distance :(

Here is my Latex Code .

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\def\benzene{\chemname[0.8ex]{\chemfig{**6(------)}}{Benzene}}

\def\nitrobenzene{\chemname[0.8ex]{\chemfig{**6(----(-NO_2)--)}}{Nitro Benzene}}


\begin{document}

% #1
\schemedebug{true}

\vspace{5mm}
        \schemestart
                \benzene 
                \arrow{0}[,0] \+ 
                \chemfig{3Cl_2} 
                \arrow{->[sunlight][uv]} 
                \chemfig{C_6H_6Cl_6} \arrow{0}[,0]  \, \, \, \,  or 
                \chemname[0.8ex]{\chemfig{*6((-Cl)-(-Cl)-(-Cl)-(-Cl)-(-Cl)-(-Cl)-)}}{Benzene Hexachloride(BHC)}
          \schemestop


% #9
\vspace{5mm}
        \schemestart
                \benzene 
                \arrow{0}[,0] 
                \+ \chemfig{3H_2} 
                \arrow{->[\chemfig{Ni}][$\Delta$,Pressure]}[0,2,]  
                \chemfig{C_6H_{12}} \arrow{0}[,0]  or \chemname[0.8ex]{\chemfig{*6(------)}}{Cyclohexane}
          \schemestop

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's the same question you had here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/251739 where I already wrote in my answer that you need to reset the distance. I linked this question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83236 where it is explained

Comment: @clemens hmm according to that adding [0.8ex] would fix the problem but it fixed for only few not for all so i posted again

Comment: Have you read in the answer to the other question that you can reset the behaviour by placing `\chemnameinit{}` after using `\chemname` (which you have used in the preamble...)?

Comment: @clemens when i do like this \chemnameinit{\chemname[0.8ex]{\chemfig{*6(------)}}{Cyclohexane}}  cyclohexane disappears.Should i show screenshot?

Comment: Place `\chemnameinit{}` (with empty argument) before `\schemestart`

Comment: @clemens thank you . I had misunderstood it . SHould i write chemnameit everytime for new compound?